# Apostrophe CMS two column layout not working

Tags: apostrophe-cms

i followed the tutorial exactly from here [link](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/layout-widgets.html) but for me the two column widget doesn't work as two columns. It just stacks on top of itself. I am not sure what Im doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated

edit:

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kiyc.png)

the green area has my two column layout but it seems like they are floating too far left and right

Comment: Can we see the code?

Comment: Do you have the CSS created for two-column, column-left, and column-right? It would help to see your code.

Comment: From looking at your code, you need to assign a width to the column classes, and a float only to the right-side div. You also will want to specify display as inline-block so that they will show up on the same row. Here's a working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vrrpvb

Answer (score 1):

The CSS part is your responsibility, it is not part of that tutorial. However, you can find a [complete, functioning example with CSS in the apostrophe-samples project](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-samples). I will add a link to that project to the tutorial you are referencing.